# Jquery autocomplete with _renderItem raises errors on up and down keypress

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I've a simple input for which I use jquery autocomplete. I want to manage the display myself so I use the `_renderItem method`. Then when navigating with the up and down arrows, this raises error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` Even stranger, this error is triggered once every two key strokes...

html:

```
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Name"/>
<ul id='ul'></ul>
```

js:

```
var data = ['bob', 'alice', 'rob'];
var my_ul = $('#ul');

var $input = $('#input').autocomplete({
    search: function(event, ui) {
        my_ul.empty();
    },
    source: data,
});

$input.data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    var el = $('<li>');
    el.append('<div>'+item.label+'</div>');
    el.appendTo(my_ul);
    return el;
};
```

here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4dw2aa75/ (open your console to see errors)

Comment: This is because there's no jquery-ui-expected metadata attached to your menu items. You can't *(at least not without significant effort)* customize the dropdown this way, you should use `_renderMenu`

Comment: you can post it as the answer :)